# Locating unknown destination with Trimble?

Tags: trimble

I would like to know if it is possible to input coordinates in Trimble Geo7x and be able to locate an unknown destination.

If so how do I input the coordinates and also to navigate to the input coordinate points destination?

Answer (score 1):

Anything's possible.  It just depends how much you are prepared to pay.

The quick answer is that Geo 7x does not come as standard with any software which would let you do this.  If you have Trimble TerraSync, which is quite common on Geo 7x, you could add a feature by enter the coordinates manually in TerraSync, then use TerraSync's Navigate function.  Other applications (ESRI ArcPad or similar) I guess they have similar functions.